# Visa question: attending a conference in the USA and accompanied by spouse

Tags: visas, usa

I'm going to attend a conference in the US and am applying for a B1 visa. While completing the DS-160 form I was asked if I will be accompanied by someone, I entered the name of my wife. Now I'm at the step of paying for the fees and scheduling an interview, and I don't think that I'm applying also for my wife's visa (there's no option to enter my wife's information such as passport number, etc...).

How should I proceed to apply for a visa for my wife, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each one needs to apply for Visa.

You will need to complete another DS-160 and follow all process for your wife. There are options for family (in Brazil I know that has) and you can go for the interview (if it is the case) in the same time.

I travel for US with my wife and my son and I need to ask a Visa in different process for each one of us.